# Comprobar que todas las filas de una matriz estén odenadas de forma descendente

Tags: python

Comprobar que todas las filas de una matriz estén odenadas de forma descendente. Si no están todos en forma descendiente encontrar la primera fila desordenada y ordenarla igual que las demas.

Con este código obtengo las filas en forma descendente:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]]

for row in matrix:
    if all(x - y > 0 for x, y in zip(row[:-1], row[1:])):
        print(row)
```

Es decir con el código comprueba las filas ordenadas en forma descendente e imprime las que si lo están:

```
[7, 1, -3]
[8, 4, -9]
```

Es necesario obtener la fila desordenada, en este caso seria la fila 0, y ordenarla igual que las otras. La salida debería ser:

```
[2, -5, -6]
[7, 1, -3]
[8, 4, -9]
```

Comment: quizas pueda ayudar que indiques que pasa o que comportamiento quieres que ocurra, si encuentra la primera que esta desordenada y la siguiente tambien lo esta, o hay otra tambien desordenada en otro lugar. quieres que la oredene todas o sola la primera que encuentre dejando las demas sin ordenar. Saludos

Comment: Te sugiero que pongas ejemplos del resultado esperado con diferentes matrices de prueba y además especifiques exactamente la parte en tu código que no tienes clara o no te da el resultado que tu esperas.

Comment: Creo que deberías poner un ejemplo con entrada y salida esperada, no se entiende lo que quieres lograr. ¿Estás usando `zip` para tratar de ordenar las filas?, ¿a qué te refieres con "ordernarlas igual que las demás"?

Comment: es decir el codigo tiene que mostrar en primer lugar solo las filas que estan ordenadas, despues las que no lo estan. Ordenarlas y volver a mostrar pero esta vez todas de manera ordenada descendente. Saludos

Comment: Si, así @AngelAngel

Comment: Como menciona @AngelAngel, en la pregunta aún no has especificado que debe hacerse si encuentra más de una fila desordenada. Al menos yo no lo tengo claro.

Comment: Intuyo que lo que buscas es simplemente ordenar tu matriz:
`for x in matrix:
    x.sort(reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, por lo que entendí de los comentarios supongo que quieres algo como esto (probado en Python 2):

```
def order_matrix(matrix):
    ordenadas = []
    desordenadas = []
    # Enumeramos los elementos para usarlos como índice
    for index, arreglo in enumerate(matrix):
        if arreglo == sorted(arreglo, reverse=True):
            ordenadas.append(arreglo)
        else:
            desordenadas.append(arreglo)
            matrix[index] = sorted(arreglo, reverse=True)
    return ordenadas, desordenadas, matrix

matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]]
# Estoy enviando una copia de la matriz, con esto puedes mantener
# la matriz original
ordenadas, desordenadas, new_matrix = order_matrix(matrix[:])
print ordenadas
print desordenadas
print new_matrix
print matrix
```

Arrojaría:

```
[[7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]]
[[-5, -6, 2]]
[[2, -5, -6], [7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]]
[[-5, -6, 2], [7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]] # Matriz original
```

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a la respuesta al comentario de Ángel, un par de `list comprehensions` hacen el trabajo sucio

```py
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 1, -3], [8, 4, -9]]

sted = [x for x in matrix if x == sorted(x, reverse=True)]
# Las no ordenadas están en matrix pero no en "sted"
nsted = [sorted(x, reverse=True) for x in matrix if x not in sted]

print('\n'.join(map(str, sted)))
print()
print('\n'.join(map(str, nsted)))
print('\n'.join(map(str, sted)))
```

Con el siguiente resultado

```
[7, 1, -3]
[8, 4, -9]

[2, -5, -6]
[7, 1, -3]
[8, 4, -9]
```

La matriz original permanece inalterada y tenemos submatrices separadas con las filas que estaban ordenadas y las no ordenadas ahora ordenadas